# ошибка при получении данных из массива Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firestore

я пишу приложение для получения промокодов, работает следующим образом: пользователь заходит, жмет на кнопку и получает значение из массива из базы данных и после это значение удаляется из базы и след. пользователь получает следующий промокод, но на практике столкнулся с проблемой, значение удаляется с небольшой задержкой (примерно в 1 с) из-за чего при практически одновременном нажатии на кнопку с разных устройств приложение получает одно и тоже значение, пробовал получать рандомное значение из базы и записывать полученное значение во второй массив и при получении сравнивать значения из первого и второго массива, но в обоих случаях опять все упирается в ту же проблему, как можно еще разрешить данную проблему?

код приложения:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    Button mButtonGive;
    Button mButtonGiveIvi;
    TextView mTextPromo;
    TextView mTextPromoIvi;

    FirebaseFirestore mRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference mDelRef = mRef.collection("Promocode").document("Delivery");
    DocumentReference mIviRef = mRef.collection("Promocode").document("Ivi");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mButtonGive = findViewById(R.id.mButtonGive);
        mButtonGiveIvi = findViewById(R.id.mButtonGiveIvi);
        mTextPromo = findViewById(R.id.mTextPromo);
        mTextPromoIvi = findViewById(R.id.mTextPromoIvi);

        mButtonGive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDelRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                                assert document != null;
                                if (document.exists()) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                                    List<String> promocodes;
                                    promocodes = (List<String>) document.get("Promocode");
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Promocodes: " + promocodes);
                                    if (promocodes.size() > 0) {
                                        mDelRef.update("Promocode", FieldValue.arrayRemove(promocodes.get(0)));
                                        mTextPromo.setText(promocodes.get(0));

                                    } else {
                                        mTextPromo.setText("Промокоды кончились");
                                        Log.d(TAG, "No Promo");
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                                }

                            }
                            else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                            }
                    }

                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно генерировать код в момент запроса и сохранять его в бд, а не удалять - иначе как потом использовать этот код? Как ты проверишь что он действительный?

Тебе придется написать серверный код используя firebase functions.

Алгоритм:
1. юзер запросил код -> сгенерировать уникальный код и записать в бд. -> вернуть юзеру
2. юзер использовал код -> проверить что он есть в бд, удалить -> выслать юзеру награду(или что там)

Comment: код не генерируемый, коды будут заранее лежать в базе, в их работоспособности я уверен на все 100

Comment: В принципе для получения кода пользователю придется посмотреть рекламный ролик, так что если есть возможность использовать firebase function или правила безопасности cloud firestore чтобы как-то ограничить одновременное получение значений из базы, скажите пожалуйста

Comment: "не генерируемый" - алгоритм тот же, по запросу перемещай код из коллекцию не занятых в коллекцию занятых

Comment: Давай еще раз попробую описать проблему. Если есть свободное время, буду рад если поможешь!  У меня есть промокоды в массиве и все находится в Cloud Firestore. Пользователь нажимает в приложении кнопку получить код и получает код с базы. Но когда несколько пользователей одновременно нажимают получить, то они могут получить одинаковы код, а этого не должно случиться так как все коды уникальные. Как избежать повторных кодов при одновременном нажатии, чтобы ни в коем случае не попадались одинаковые. Можешь подробно описать как это сделать, буду очень благодарен. Я в этом новичок и плохо понимаю.

Comment: чем не такой алгоритм выше? Тебе нужно обдумать структуру - реализация на массивах - это не верно, например ты знаешь что массив ограничен в размерах?

Comment: Ну это все равно, спокойно можно настроить несколько массивов чотбы работали как продолжение друг друга, а мой алгоритм плох тем что получение всего массива в приложение происходит моментально, а удаление значения из него уже с задержкой в 1 секунду где-то, из-за чего и получается, что на разных устройствах один промокод